# jQuery tab widget in a dialog: display error

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery tab widget inside a dialog. When the Advisers image is clicked for the first time in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/8UBQF/), the dialog and the tab widget display fine. If however the dialog is closed and the image is clicked a second time, the dialog renders but the tab widget doesn't.

I think it has to do with the `toggle()` method used on the tab widget but if I remove that method, the tab widget never displays. It's almost like I need to 'reinitialise' the page state when the dialog is closed in order to get the tab dialog to render on the second and subsequent click of the Adviser image (forgive my grappling with UI terminology here, I'm a server-side coder).

Can anyone give me a pointer, please?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="advisers-image">
    <div class="circle hovershadow advisers advisers-box-shadow text">Professional
        advisers</div>
</a>

<a href="#" id="industry-image">
    <div class="circle hovershadow industry industry-box-shadow">Industry</div>
</a>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div id="advisers-dialog" class="dialog">

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Law firms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Accounting and audit firms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Management consultants and economists</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Law firm text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Accounting and audit firm text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Management consultants and economists text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="industry-dialog" class="dialog" title="Industry">Industry
    text goes here</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#tabs" ).tabs().hide();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">         
$( "#industry-dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#industry-image" ).click(function() {
$( "#industry-dialog" ).dialog( "option", "modal", true );
$( "#industry-dialog" ).dialog( "option", "height", "auto" );
$( "#industry-dialog" ).dialog( "option", "width", 700 );
$( "#industry-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">         
$( "#advisers-dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#advisers-image" ).click(function() {
$( "#advisers-dialog" ).dialog( "option", "modal", true );
$( "#advisers-dialog" ).dialog( "option", "height", "auto" );
$( "#advisers-dialog" ).dialog( "option", "width", 700 );
$( "#advisers-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "heightStyle", "content" );
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( 'select', 0 );
$( "#tabs" ).toggle();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple fix is to call

```
$( "#tabs" ).show();
```

instead of

```
$( "#tabs" ).toggle();
```

`.show()` simply makes an element visible, regardless of its current state, whereas `.toggle()` toggles it.

In this particular case, I don't know why you even need to hide the `#tabs` initially. They are inside the dialog and won't be seen. If you don't `.hide()` them initially, you don't need to call `.show()` later. See jsFiddle revision: http://jsfiddle.net/8UBQF/1/

Answer (score 1):

Basic reason is every time you click image you call `$( "#tabs" ).toggle();`.

So on even number of clicks the tabs will be hidden, on odd number of clicks they will be visible. Shouldn't be a need to hide the tabs to begin with since they are contained within a dialog which is set to hidden.

Additional note:

Since options are duplicated for both dialogs, no need to set them every time they open. Can consolidate into original options object and share one object for both dialogs and reduce a lot of code.

```
var commonDialogOptions={
    autoOpen: false,
    modal:true,
    width:700
}
$("#industry-dialog, #advisers-dialog").dialog(commonDialogOptions);
```

This will remove the setting of options within the click handlers. If you need to individually set specific options can do that on as needed basis

Reduced code demo , removing tabs hide/show: http://jsfiddle.net/8UBQF/2/

Comment: Thank you charlietfl - I upvoted your answer because of the commonDialogOptions input, a very good idea. Tcovo was first to answer so I accepted his/her answer. Thank you again for your time.